# Correct Approach for Fractional Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am stuggling with this inequality and it seems to have tripped up my professor too.
$$\frac{3}{x}-2<8$$

My initial answer was
$$\frac{3}{x}<10$$
$$3<10x$$
$$\frac{3}{10}<x$$
Then I checked the solution sheet my professor provided and he found 
$$x>\frac{3}{10}, x<-\frac{3}{10}, x\ne0$$
Curious, I checked Wolfram Alfpha, MathPapa and Symbolab and they all disagreed 
$$x<0, x>\frac{3}{10}$$
I'm assuming that the websites (computer algebra systems?) are correct and both my professor and I are wrong but I still don't know how to approach such problems systematically. How can I ensure I don't make mistakes like this is the future?

Comment: Why "assume"? Just try out some representative values in the areas of uncertainty and see which solution actually works. The key is that if $x$ is negative and you multiply through by $x$ then the inequality is reversed, so you have not found the whole solution, but only the part where $x\gt 0$. Often it is useful to sketch a graph if you are in any doubt.

Comment: If $x\lt 0$, then $\frac 3x\lt 10$ holds. If $x\gt 0$, then $\frac 3x\lt 10$ is equivalent to $3\lt 10x$, i.e. $x\gt \frac{3}{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $x^2$ to get $3x < 10x^2$. Rearrange and factorize the terms to get $x(10x-3)>0$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: This is right with the observation that $x^2\neq 0$ - the key is that if you multiply by a positive number the inequality remains valid. Multiplication by a negative number reverses it. Multiplication by zero collapses it to a trivial equality.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3}{x}-2<8\quad\implies 3-2x<8x\quad\implies 3<10x\quad \implies x>\frac{3}{10}<x$$

However multiplying both sides of $3<10x$ by $-1$ reverses things: $$-3>-10x\quad\implies -x<-\frac{3}{10}>-x$$
and here it looks like your professor forgot to change the sign of $x$.

You could square both sides and take the square root of that and get $$x^2=\bigg(-\frac{3}{10}\bigg)^2\quad\implies x<\sqrt{\bigg(-\frac{3}{10}\bigg)^2}=\bigg(\pm\frac{3}{10}\bigg)>x$$

but that's fudging things and does not mean the latter answer is necessarily correct.